# Rails - Active admin or datatables? - Create Filters Dynamically and Save it to the database for next time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filter, datatables, admin, activeadmin

I have 2 questions for implementing Admin page on Rails

1. Which is the best approach for admin section ..  datatables(jQuery, also supports serverside processsing) or activeadmin(Full HTML requests) ?
2. How enable any user to create a filter of the table and save it in the DB, so that for the next time when he logs into the system, he can use it?